# Spring Boot connection to ANY remote MySQL database in runtime

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, database-connection

#### Overview

I'd like to create a simple app which will allow end user to connect via web to any database instance he wants as long as it will be MySQL or MongoDB one. The app will allow the end user to perform any SQL / MQL operation in its textarea and will return the query results as well. The app will be *the lightest* version possible of softwares like MySQLTools or Studio 3T - it should only do 3 things:

- connect to the given database,
- perform a query,
- return results.

#### Problem

But the thing is I don't actually have an idea how to create that kind of connection. I've never had to do such things.
I guess the connection should be stored as a session / cookie somehow.

So the actual questions are:
**How can I let the user provide credentials for database connection?** and
**How can I store that connection for later usage?**

#### Techstack

- Java 8
- Spring Boot
- Angular 9